# Mongo Zone Sharding Implementation Issue

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.6

As I am new with MongoDB.

I have configured 2 config server, 2 shards and all are connected with mongod client. Also, One Mongos client is UP and Running.

I am currenctly implementing Sharding using Mongo Zone. As I have to store the data accourding to country/Zone. But facing below error in shards:

```
2018-05-03T16:22:40.200+0530 W SHARDING [conn13] Chunk move failed :: caused by :: 
      NoShardingEnabled: Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr
2018-05-03T16:27:11.223+0530 I SHARDING [Balancer] Balancer move testdb.user: 
      [{ zipcode: "380001" }, { zipcode: "39000" }), from rs1, to rs0 failed :: caused by :: 
      NoShardingEnabled: Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr
```

I have already started server with `--shardsvr` and also mentioned in config file as well. But still I am facing issue.

Below are the all config files:

**mongosconfig.cfg**

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "c:\\data\\log\\mongos.log"
  logAppend: true
sharding:
  configDB: "rs0/192.168.1.113:27017,192.168.1.112:27017"
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.1.113
  port: 27018
```

**mongoclientconfig.cfg** - configserver1

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "c:\\data\\log\\mongoclient.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "c:\\data\\db\\configdb"
  journal:
    enabled: true
sharding:
  clusterRole: "configsvr"
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.1.113
  port: 27017
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

**mongodconfig.cfg** - shard1

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "c:\\data\\log\\mongod.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "c:\\data\\db\\clientdb"
  journal:
    enabled: true
sharding:
  clusterRole: "shardsvr"
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.1.113
  port: 27019
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

**mongoclientconfig.cfg** - configserver2

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "D:\\data\\log\\mongoclient.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "D:\\data\\db\\configdb"
  journal:
    enabled: true
sharding:
  clusterRole: "configsvr"
replication:
  replSetName: "rs1"
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.1.112
  port: 27017
```

**mongodconfig.cfg** - Shard2

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "D:\\data\\log\\mongod.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "D:\\data\\db\\clientdb"
  journal:
    enabled: true
sharding:
  clusterRole: "shardsvr"
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.1.112
  port: 27019
replication:
  replSetName: "rs1"
```

Below are the commands which i have used for zone wise sharding as per the mongodb documentation(official):

```
rs.initiate({_id: "rs0",members: [{ _id : 0, host : "192.168.1.113:27019" }]}) //for shard1
rs.initiate({_id: "rs1",members: [{ _id : 1, host : "192.168.1.112:27019" }]}) //for shard2

sh.addShard("rs0/192.168.1.113:27019"); //Adding shard1 from mongos client
sh.addShard("rs1/192.168.1.112:27019"); //Adding shard2 from mongos client
sh.addShardToZone("rs0","IND");
sh.addShardToZone("rs1","UK");
sh.addTagRange("testdb.user", {zipcode: "380001"}, {zipcode: "390000"}, 
"IND");
sh.addTagRange("testdb.user", {zipcode: "400000"}, {zipcode: "600000"}, 
"UK");
sh.shardCollection("testdb.user", { zipcode: 1 } );
```

Please help me get this resolve.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you include your config file?

Comment: @AnkitJani, As your error shown that "NoShardingEnabled". Did you check that you config server  is running or not .

Comment: @LowlyDBA, I have added all the config files which i have used for the implementation of zone wise sharding and also added commands which i have used for the same.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan, Yes I have checked that, config servers are running properly.

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is your `replSetName:` parameters.

BOTH config servers must be at same replica set, f.ex. `conf` and then those shards (data nodes) both should have different replica set names. f.ex. rs0 and rs1.

Now your config1 is `rs0` and config2 is `rs1`.

Comment: Thanks @JJussi

This is for replicating the data within both the servers but I am trying the example for GDPR where I dont need to replicate the data across the Shards.

I want to do data distribution not the replication using zone sharding.

Comment: It looks like that you don't understand how clustering (sharding) works. ;-) Config server(s) are common to ALL shards. Config server must be replica set (replica set can be one node or multiple node replica set). Single shard can be single node, single node replica set or multiple node replica set. After that you have one or more mongoS services to where clients connect.